# Android ListView wraps inside a parent while shouldn't

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I'm developing an android app.
there are multiple navigation drawers in my main activity. They are defined like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/black"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:background="#e1fcff"
    />
<ListView android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/black"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:background="#e1fcff"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-64dp"
    />

<ListView android:id="@+id/contacts_drawer_right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#ffff2a00"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:background="#e1fcff"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-64dp"
    />
```

I fill the "contacts_drawer_right listview" with a RelativeLayout which has a listView (with id=contactsListView) in its inside too.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"><ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/contactsListView"
            />
    </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is that, the contactsListView does not fill it's parent height, although I've used `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` in it's definition layout file.
My expectation is like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V72Ns.gif)
But what happens in reality is like below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BNqn.png)
moreover I can not scroll the listview too.

please give me ideas and show me how I can show all the contents of my listview(with filled parent).

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this, make scrollView the parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
              <ListView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/contactsListView"
                />
         </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: you can remove scrollView if you just want a listview .... listView is already scrollable why would you want to add a scrollView ??